# How do I eliminate rows by group?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a `tbl` like this, grouped by `var1`:

```
var1 var2
A    2
A    3
A    0
B    0
B    2
B    1
C    0
C    0
C    0
```

I was wondering if there's a way to get rid of the groups with all zeros in `var2`, for example in this data set the group `c` should be removed, like this:

```
var1 var2
A    2
A    3
A    0
B    0
B    2
B    1
```

Is there an easy way to do using dplyr? I would like an answer using only functions in `dplyr` and `tidyr`, connected by `%>%`.

Comment: Since noone likes base R any more, i'll just leave an answer as a comment: `dat[with(dat,ave(var2!=0L,var1,FUN=any)),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
library('dplyr')
tbl %>% 
   group_by(var1) %>%
   filter(!all(var2 == 0))
```

Comment: Very good! Thanks! But why not `filter` directly? This way you don't have to get rid of the new column with another `select`.

Comment: Just for verbosity. You can also filter directly if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 tbl %>%
   group_by(var1) %>%
   mutate(var3 = ifelse(mean(var2) == 0, 1, 0))
   filter(var3 != 1)
```

Comment: this won't wok. What if the var2 = c(-1, 1)?

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl %>%
   group_by(var1) %>%
   filter(sum(var2)!= 0)
```

Comment: OP question is: get rid of the groups with all zeros in var2.